# Rewrite the ODE as a two dimensional, first order, autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the one dimensional, first order, non-autonomous ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x)$$

1. Rewrite this as a two dimensional, first order, autonomous ODE by introducing a new function
   $\tau(t) = t$. Your answer should include two equations - one of the form $dx/dt = ···$ and the
   other of the form $d\tau/dt = ···$. The system should be autonomous, so you should not have
   any $t$’s in your formulas.
2. Repeat this using $\tau(t)=e^t$.
3. Why is the same method not possible if you were to use $\tau(t)=t^2$?

Can I get some verification on my attempt? Additionally, I want to know where the function $\tau(t)$ came from. It was given in the problem, but if I were to make this transformation without a given function, how would I derive it? Thank you.

**My Attempt**

1. First, we will substitute $t=\tau$ into our function to get rid of the $t$'s
   $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(\tau,x)$$

Then differentiating $\tau(t)=t$, we get
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=1$$
Altogether, our system of differential equations is
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(\tau,x)$$
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=1$$
2. Using $\tau(t)=e^t$, we first want to solve for $t$ so we can plug it into our function.
$$\tau(t)=e^t\implies t=\ln(\tau)$$
Then the derivative of $\tau(t)=e^t$ is
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=e^t=\tau$$
So altogether, our system of differential equations is
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(\ln(\tau),x)$$
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\tau$$

3. If we use $\tau(t)=t^2$, then differentiating it, we get
   $$\frac{d\tau}{dt}=2t$$ and we cannot get rid of the $t$, so we cannot make it autonomous.

Comment: This all looks correct, but you should try elaborating further on the last question, appealing to the fact that $2t$ cannot be expressed in terms of $t^2,$ except by using piecewise functions.